# Adjacency matrix from polygons in GeoJSON

Tags: polygon, geojson, adjacency

I have a set of polygon features in a GeoJSON file. They are neigbourhoods in Chicago. I would like to produce an adjacency matrix A, in CSV format or any other form, where the i,j element of A is 1 if Pi is adjacent to Pj (i.e. they are touching).

Is there any tool that can easily read the file and do this?

Comment: Are you prepared to use Postgis? You could import the GeoJSON to geometries, run a spatial self-join using ST_Touches and then export to csv using Postgres's Copy  command. There are undoubtedly other tools, but that is how I would do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in R using `gTouches` in the [rgeos package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/rgeos.pdf).
Use [rgdal package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/rgdal.pdf) to open your geojson:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)

polys <- readOGR("polys.json", "OGRGeoJSON")
gTouches(polys, byid=TRUE)
```

With success, will produce an adjacency matrix in the form of:

```
##       0     1     2     3   
## 0 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
## 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
## 2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Do you know something to do the same in Python, @toms?